# Pass javascript variable to php without a form and redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass a JS variable to php without a form. In simple words I got the current slide of the flexslider and I passed like a variable in javascript for after convert it to PHP variable and redirect it to the step "step_3.php".

I tried to used an ajax but it didn't work.

step_2.php

```
 <a href="#" id="btn_next">Next Step</a>
    <script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {
          $("#btn_next").click(function() {
              var face = $('.flexslider').data('flexslider').currentSlide;
              /*transform var face to PHP and redirect to step_3.php */
      });
    </script>
```

step_3.php

```
get the value
```

If any could help me i would appreciate a lot

Comment: You may be saying, but I'm having trouble getting it maybe. Are you trying to go to another page and send the variable to that page?

Comment: what is .currentSlide ?

Comment: @rodboc You can send your variable to `PHP` using `POST AJAX` request by which you won't have to use a `FORM`.But, as `PHP` is a server-side language to you must send the variable to the server in order to hand-over to `PHP` using `GET` or `POST` request.

Comment: @golgothan3 yes, that it is :)

Comment: @samitha it's a function to get the current slide in flexslider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
          $("#btn_next").click(function() {
              var face = $('.flexslider').data('flexslider').currentSlide;
location.href = "step_3.php?face="+face;
      });
```

And then in `step_3.php` you process the face value and continue doing your things

Comment: Thanks I used `$( document ).ready(function() {
      $("#btn_next").click(function() {
      var face = $('.flexslider').data('flexslider').currentSlide;
      window.location.href = "step_03.php?cara="+ face;
    });`

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect with javascript by setting the url like this `window.location.href = url.com` and tack a GET variable onto the end of it like `window.location.href = url.com?var=value` and on the page you redirect to, get the variable in PHP with

```
$var = $_GET['var'];
```

Comment: Thanks, finally is used your recommendation to get the value of the var